# Why I cannot edit gl_FragCoord?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

As title, 
I have this line in the fragment shader of a WebGL program,

```
gl_FragCoord.xy = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x + 1.0,gl_FragCoord.y);
```

and the Google Chrome console tells:

ERROR: 0:45: 'assign' :  l-value required "gl_FragCoord" (can't modify gl_FragCoord)

Why?

Comment: As a general rule, you move things in the vertex shader (gl_Position) and color things in the fragment shader (gl_FragColor). So you'll want to move your logic to the vertex shader if you're moving things around.

Comment: In fact, in the end I arrived to that, but that might be useful for the next coming :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gl_FragCoord` is the coordinate of the fragment your shader currently runs on. You cannot dynamically choose the fragment you're processing "for parallelization reasons" and because "GPUs are not designed that way", if you want to know more read up on GPU architecture, a great resource to do so would be [A trip through the Graphics Pipeline by Fabian Giesen aka ryg](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-index/).

> Available only in the fragment language, gl_FragCoord is an input variable that contains the window relative coordinate (x, y, z, 1/w) values for the fragment. If multi-sampling, this value can be for any location within the pixel, or one of the fragment samples. ***This value is the result of fixed functionality that interpolates primitives after vertex processing to generate fragments***. 
>   [OpenGL SDK Doc](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml)

Comment: Could You give a more complete answer..? At least a reference to the "parallelization reasons"

Comment: I've added more information and a reference, check out part 8 and 9 of *A trip through the graphics pipeline*. Btw. even if it was possible your code would just offset the final image to the right by one pixel, so whats the point?

Comment: It was just a toy example.. I need to make a much more complex transformation